# PHP Profiler with method execution count, times etc. without extensions

Tags: php, methods, profiler, execution-time

Is there any class or library that I can use for profiling, finding bottlenecks, seeing unnecessary execution times etc in my local php environment using beside the CI's default profiler?

I'm going to use it remotely and my host doesn't have any debug extensions installed, and I don't want to ask them to install, and if there's any PHP solution of it, it'll be nice.

If possible, without installing an extension or altering php.ini file please.

(I edited the title because it made the question look Codeigniter specific, but it's not.)

Comment: This is what xdebug can be used for.

Comment: I have xdebug installed but never looked how to use it. I'll try.

Comment: Ok, now I realized that I have xdebug locally but I'm gonna do the profiling remotely :) so I'm updating the question.

Comment: You'll probably also want kcachegrind to handle the profiling output to make it human-readable

Comment: cachegrind is configured in php.ini and keeps it's logs in tmp folder, and I don't have access to both of them remotely. Thanks.

Comment: have you looked at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html ?

Comment: yes I've looked that before and I'm already using a modded profiler on my page. and I'm looking for some ready, plug'n play solution if exists for the method execution count and individual times spent. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XHProf from the Facebook team

http://internetwebsitedesign.biz/tutorials/advanced-codeigniter-profiling-with-xhprof

Code available here:

https://github.com/facebook/xhprof

Comment: Ok, can it be installed without using linux bash or php.ini setting alteration? just copy paste?